# Cucumber the same random class in diffrent scenarios

Tags: java, cucumber

I have Two Cucumber scenarios.
On each sceanrio I want to use the same random_document

in my Steps class I have:

```
public class PatientCreateSteps {
private final String RANDOM_DOCUMENT='ABC'+RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic

....
```

#in the featurefile:
Scenario:  Add patient documentation

```
@When ("StepsFromScenarioI)
.....
@Then("StepsFromScenarioI)
```

Scenario: Update patients documentaion

```
@When("StepsFromScenarioII)
```

Is it possible to change something to not generating new RANDOM_DOCUMENT in the second class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want the same random string in *all* scenarios in a single test run you could make it static.

```
public class PatientCreateSteps {
private static final String RANDOM_DOCUMENT='ABC'+RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic

....
```

But if you are trying to share a specific document between two scenarios you can not do that.

Consider creating it from scratch and specifying what exactly needs to be the same. For example

```
Scenario: A patient with a document
  Given a patient
  And a document for that patient
  ...


Scenario: A patient with the same document as another patient
  Given a patient
  And a document for that patient that is the same as another patients document
  ...
```

Here after creating the patient you'd create a second patient and give him a document, the give the first patient a copy of the second patients document.

This may sound in efficient. Especially if you're used to manually test things. But computers are pretty fast and/or can do things in parallel. So it's more important to keep each scenario independent.